# iOS Button Text Localization - do you have to do the whole xib file?

Tags: ios, localization

I'm working on getting an iOS app translated into Russian.  All is going well except for the text on buttons.

It seems like the size of the English text defines the size that the Russian text can fit into.  Since most of the Russian text is longer, it is getting cut off even though the button has plenty or empty space to the right of this text.

I've set the text on the buttons inside the viewWillAppear method.  Is there a better way to handle this, or does the whole xib file need to be localized?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the button's [autosizing settings](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW5)? That would be the most likely cause of cut-off text with space to spare in the button. You can set the autosizing attributes in Xcode or programmatically with [`UIView::autoresizingMask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask).

You should not need to localize the XIB if you're setting the text in code. Autosizing should fix the issue.